python watchdog output repeated logs when event happen
I am trying to monitor a folder using watchdog, the problem is I dont understand why watchdog observer output multiple logs when one event happens. The code I used is shown below, it is a very basic code that I found on the internet.

# import the modules
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set the format for logging info
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
 
    # Set format for displaying path
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
 
    # Initialize logging event handler
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
 
    # Initialize Observer
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
 
    # Start the observer
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            # Set the thread sleep time
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()

2024-08-26 09:38:21 - Created file: .\from\test_folder\testwatchdog.txt
2024-08-26 09:38:21 - Modified directory: .\from\test_folder
2024-08-26 09:38:21 - Modified file: .\from\test_folder\testwatchdog.txt
2024-08-26 09:38:55 - Deleted file: .\from\test_folder\testwatchdog.txt
2024-08-26 09:38:55 - Created file: .\testwatchdog.txt
2024-08-26 09:39:07 - Moved file: from .\testwatchdog.txt to .\testwatchdogs.txt
2024-08-26 09:39:21 - Modified file: .\testwatchdogs.txt
2024-08-26 09:39:21 - Modified file: .\testwatchdogs.txt
2024-08-26 09:39:21 - Modified file: .\testwatchdogs.txt
2024-08-26 09:39:39 - Modified file: .\testwatchdogs.txt
2024-08-26 09:39:39 - Modified file: .\testwatchdogs.txt
2024-08-26 09:39:39 - Modified file: .\testwatchdogs.txt

The last 6lines, what i did is just modified twice
I have tried some other methods, but it still do the same thing. I am not sure where the problem is.

Look at this answer.  The gist of it is that some tools that modify files do multiple operations on the file that the underlying operating system is reporting to you.
